# How to traverse through the following loop in dart?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, dart

```
 {"products": [
    {
        "prod_id": "prod-345",
        "name": "Something",
        "category": "Cloth",
        "thumbnail": "",
        "rating": 1,
    },
    {
        "prod_id": "prod-123",
        "name": "Something Else",
        "category": "Watch",
        "thumbnail": "",
        "rating": 1,
    },
 ]}
```

I want to traverse through the list using for each but am not able to do so. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
ProductReply data = productReplyFromJson(jsonString);
for(int i=0;i<data.products.length;i++){
print(data.products[i]. name);
}
```

Define class to hold data as

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final productReply = productReplyFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

ProductReply productReplyFromJson(String str) => ProductReply.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String productReplyToJson(ProductReply data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ProductReply {
    List<Product> products;

    ProductReply({
        this.products,
    });

    factory ProductReply.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProductReply(
        products: List<Product>.from(json["products"].map((x) => Product.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "products": List<dynamic>.from(products.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Product {
    String prodId;
    String name;
    String category;
    String thumbnail;
    int rating;

    Product({
        this.prodId,
        this.name,
        this.category,
        this.thumbnail,
        this.rating,
    });

    factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Product(
        prodId: json["prod_id"],
        name: json["name"],
        category: json["category"],
        thumbnail: json["thumbnail"],
        rating: json["rating"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "prod_id": prodId,
        "name": name,
        "category": category,
        "thumbnail": thumbnail,
        "rating": rating,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Map> products = [];

 @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    Map tmp = {"products": [
    {
        "prod_id": "prod-345",
        "name": "Something",
        "category": "Cloth",
        "thumbnail": "",
        "rating": 1,
    },
    {
        "prod_id": "prod-123",
        "name": "Something Else",
        "category": "Watch",
        "thumbnail": "",
        "rating": 1,
    },
 ]};
    products.addAll(tmp['products']);
  }


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Let\'s parse some JSON'),
      ),
      body: Container(
      padding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5,10,5,10),
      child:ListView.builder(
      itemCount:products.length,
      itemBuilder:(cc,ind){
        return ListTile(
        title:Text(products[ind]['name'])
        );
      }
      )
      )
    );
  }
```